# JSON + Jquery. What am I doing wrong? Simple output of JSON not working

Tags: jquery, json

I am trying to loop through this external JSON file(locally stored), but I cannot get it to read the values and keys properly. What am I doing wrong?

This is driving me crazy and I have tried a million combinations of markup and have tried other methods, but I keep ending up in the same place.

Really appreciate any help.

Also the code does not output

## JSON FILE cars.js (local file)

```
window.cars = { 

    "compact": [

        { "title": "honda", 
          "type": "accord", 
          "thumbnail": "accord_t.jpg", 
          "image": "accord_large.jpg" }, 

        { "title": "volkswagon", 
          "type": "rabbit",
          "thumbnail": "rabbit_t.jpg",    
          "image": "volkswagon_large.jpg" } 

    ],

    "trucks": [

        { "title": "Ford", 
          "type": "f-150", 
          "thumbnail": "ford_t.jpg", 
          "image": "chevy_large.jpg" },

        { "title": "GMC", 
          "type": "silverado", 
          "thumbnail": "gmc_t.jpg", 
          "image": "gmc_large.jpg" }

    ]

};
```

## HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){ 

$.ajax ({      

url: 'cars.js',      
type: 'get', 
dataType: 'json',  
error: function(result){ alert('No Dice')},
success: function(result){

    $('body').append('<div class="main_wrapper"></div><ul>');

        $.each(cars.trucks, function( k, v){

        $('ul').append('<li class="trucks"><img src="' + v.k[1].thumbnail + '" />
                <h1>Title:' +  v.k[1].title + ' </h1>
                <h2>Type: ' + v.k[1].type + '</h2></li>');
        });

        $.each(cars.compact, function( k, v){

       $('ul').append('<li class="compact"><img src="' + v.k[0].thumbnail + '" />
                <h1>Title:' +  v.k[0].title + ' </h1>
                 <h2>Type: ' + v.k[0].type + '</h2></li>');
       });

}

});

});
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What if you try datatype = 'text/javascript'? In any case I'd say you're misusing the ajax function and the result is not json. You're not calling any server logic, just loading an js file

Comment: Not working. The json file does not load if I do the dataType to text/javascript. The js file has json data.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I wanted to say dataType = "script" as @Roman Bataev pointed out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure your web server is configured properly, so it actually returns the content of static cars.js file. Second, remove "windows.cars = " and semicolon from the file. You are loading data, not a script, so it's got to be pure json. Then, in success function *result* will be your json object, so should be able to access result.trucks and result.compact properties (**not** cars.trucks / cars.compact)

UPDATE:
After further reading on dataType setting at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings, I think you should be able to get you code working if you change dataType from "json" to "script".

Comment: I have MAMP and all the files are under htdocs. Ok thanks, I'll try it.

Comment: the .js file won't load if I remove the "window.cars = " and the last semi-colon.

Comment: I add 'script' and the file loaded but no data was rendered. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're after: **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/A3NEU/)**.

It looks like you were mixing up jQuery's .each() with regular a JavaScript for...in loop. also you had some white space that might have been an issue in your loops.

jQuery:

```
$.each(cars.trucks, function(k, v) {
    $('ul').append('<li class="trucks"><img src="' + v.thumbnail + '" /><h1>Title:' + v.title + ' </h1><h2>Type: ' + v.type + '</h2></li>');
});
$.each(cars.compact, function(k, v) {
    $('ul').append('<li class="compact"><img src="' + v.thumbnail + '" /><h1>Title:' + v.title + ' </h1><h2>Type: ' + v.type + '</h2></li>');
});​
```

Comment: Yep!, but the file has to be external. Any ideas on how to do that?

Comment: I didn't see anything wrong with your JSON file. Some of the other comments/answers tell you to make sure you're getting the proper JSON response which in this case I'm assuming you are. My answer is focusing more on manipulating the data your return with rather than making sure the server is sending it properly.

Comment: Hope I was able to help. Was the problem the server sending the JSON or the jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

See [jQuery SyntaxError: Unexpected token =](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9969757/144665).

JavaScript string lines must be end with .